# Building String with slashes

Tags: java, json, string, stringbuilder

I want to send notifications using OneSignal. Json body looks following:

```
String strJsonBody = "{"
            +   "\"include_player_ids\": [\"xxxxxxx-8b43-yyyy-86d9-zzzzzzzzz\",\"xxxxxxx-50d7-yyyyy-9998-zzzzzzzzz\"],"
            +   "\"data\": {\"foo\": \"bar\"},"
            +   "\"contents\": {\"en\": \"English Message\"}"
            + "}";
```

It works, but I don't want player ids hardcoded - I would like to have them in a variable. I tried to use StringBuilder but couldn't achieve it. How can I get

```
[\"xxxxxxx-8b43-yyyy-86d9-zzzzzzzzz\",\"xxxxxxx-50d7-yyyyy-9998-zzzzzzzzz\"]
```

from

```
xxxxxxx-8b43-yyyy-86d9-zzzzzzzzz
```

and

```
xxxxxxx-50d7-yyyyy-9998-zzzzzzzzz
```

? My main problems: slashes, comma between two elements

Additional explanation:
The ids are received from Database in Object format

Comment: simply parse it using jsonobject and fetch your data

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: Building your own JSON in strings is almost always the wrong approach. Put your data into a data structure and have a JSON library handle the conversion to JSON syntax for you. It is a very finicky format.

Answer (score -1):

You were on the right track using StringBuilder. Just use multiple appends. I suspect what is throwing you off is that you are trying to insert back-slashes into your JSON. They don't belong.

Comment: I'd say that using StringBuilder is the *wrong* track. To build JSON correctly, use a JSON library.

Comment: But the problem with comma still remains. If I add it at the end of each id, then I will have comma at the end, if at the beginning -  I will have a commaas a first character

Comment: And by the way - this example is taken from official One Signal documentation ! So it was not my own idea to build it that way...